# Create a text file using client side code

Tags: javascript, json

Is there a way to create a text file (and write some JSON data to it ) using client side code only (no server-side code / web services )?

Comment: 1 way I can think of is to store your JSON string into cookie.

Comment: refer this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055391/writing-data-to-a-local-text-file-with-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i create a file on client side by JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950131/how-can-i-create-a-file-on-client-side-by-javascript)

Comment: sure <a download>, downloadify, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage) to store data client-side, but there is no way to do this server-side.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that you need to use javascript `localstorage` to store json.

example :

```
var myObject = {};
localstorage['myKey'] = myObject;
var secObject = localstorage['mykey'];

//you couls also use :
localstorage.setItem('myKey', myObject);
secObject = localstorge.getItem('myKey');
```

I usually "stringify" my JSON before saving it in case i need to modify "myObject" after saving it (because when you copy an object you actually copy a reference to it)

```
localstorage['myKey'] = JSON.stringify(myObject);
secObject = JSON.parse(localstorage['myKey']);
```

Comment: localStorage is like a temp file , that would get deleted when browser cache is cleared. Wat I want is a .txt file in a directory I specify (not somewhere browser stores the cache)

Answer (score 0):

How are you all missing his point? You are able to generate text files and .csv files on client side and deliver it as a download.

```
var element = document.createElement('a');
 element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);
  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  element.click();
  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

// Start file download.
download("hello.txt","This is the content of my file :)");
```

From this link: 
https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server