# Convert textbox content to file before submitting form

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, multipartform-data

I have a form that is posted via ajax (jQuery):

```
<form>
    <textarea name="content">here is my content</textarea>
    <input type="button" name="makefile" id="makefile">
</form>
```

and the jquery code:

```
 $('#makefile').on('click',function(){
   $.ajax({
           url: 'posturl',
           data: {
               content : //??somehow converted textbox data??//
           }
   });
 });
```

Now for the tricky part:
I want the contents of the textarea to be sent as multipart/form-data, so that the server-side script can handle the data as if it were an uploaded text file.
It seems to me that I need a method to convert the content box to a .txt file before it is submitted.

Is this at all possible? And if yes, how?

Comment: I'm curious - what advantage does it give you if the data comes to you as a file instead of a string?

Comment: Have you tried adding  `contentType: 'multipart/form-data', type: 'POST'` to your AJAX call?

Comment: Check this thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950131/how-can-i-create-a-file-on-client-side-by-javascript)

Comment: @SurrealDreams The server-side code is an API call (to elfinder) that uploads a file to the filesystem. The method expects a multipart/formdata object as specified here: https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Client-Server-API-2.0#upload

Comment: @toxels87 Perhaps it's an option to just send the plain-text data to the server and construct the textfile there and also post it from there?

Comment: @TobiasBeuving : I ended up using a similar method to the one you suggested.
For anyone interested in doing this with the elfinder API: I used a 'mkfile' call first, and then a 'put' call to add the contents on the newly created file.