# Using javascript to save XHR file

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey

I would like to save an JSON file which is requested on an after-login page with a POST request. Because there is no API available, I would like to download the response of an script called when loading the page as JSON file using Greasemonkey.

The page is like domain.com/map, which calls domain.com/map/script during the load: `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> function open() {$.ajax{{ url: "/script", type: "POST", dataType: "json",), [...] }); }; function functionname(value){ [...] }; open();`. The response of domain.com/map/script is the actual JSON response I would like to save (locally or even better using FTP).

Comment: https://github.com/rndme/download makes the actual saving part trivial, you can handle the rest of the monkey business...

Comment: I think this answers your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950131/how-can-i-create-a-file-for-storage-on-the-client-side-with-javascript

Answer (score 3):

full demo code below:

```js
(function (fetch, console) {

    fetch('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/36132760?site=stackoverflow')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.save(data));

    console.save = function (data, filename) {

            if (!data) {
                console.error('Console.save: No data')
                return;
            }

            if (!filename) filename = 'console.json'

            if (typeof data === "object") {
                data = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4);
            }

            var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/json'}),
                e    = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
                a    = document.createElement('a');

            a.download = filename;
            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            a.dataset.downloadurl =  ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':');
            e.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            a.dispatchEvent(e);
    };

}).call(this, window.fetch, window.console || {});
```

checkout [devtools-snippets#console-save](http://bgrins.github.io/devtools-snippets/#console-save)

Comment: Tnx! Would you be able to post a code example for my case? I would like to give the bounty!

Comment: @Remco I have added full demo code above, little ES6 syntax for help tho.

Comment: I would like to use this script as UserScript with Greasemonkey. It needs to wait for the "domain.com/map/script" response coming in (when calling "domain.com/map", ``$.ajax({ url: "/script", type: "POST", dataType: "json",``), then saving it. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Just perform saving inside response callback will do, e.g.:  `$.ajax().then(data => console.save(data))`

Comment: Seems the right approach. ``$.ajax({ [...] });    };    function functionname(value){`` is the code around the POST-call. Might you help me with a greasemonkey script to replace that part in the code before loading?

Comment: The ajax code is included in an ``<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> function open() { [...] }; open();``, located in the header of the page (which I don't have write access to).

Comment: Sorry I don't familiar with greasemonkey, but I think as long as it runs inside browser, the saving functionality would just do the trick, no?

Comment: Yes, but because I can't edit the page, I need an browser script to edit the page at loading (blocking the JS of the page and inserting a new one with saving function).

Comment: Then what's the problem exactly? If you have issue with greasemonkey alone, consider post another question on that I think.

Comment: This piece of code asks for the URL, but I need a code that saves the response when loading the page. I can't paste the URL because a HTTPS connection after login..