# How to update csv file using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using Google Map API and CSV file to plot the data on the map. Now I want to update the CSV file using JavaScript, so that the plotted points can be shown as moving objects in the map. I have used an active-X object. It updates the CSV file in IE only. Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var test = [
    "2015-03-03 18:12:12.297,1,19.1618,73.002,0.0",
    "2015-03-03 18:12:12.297,2,19.158141,73.000202,0.0",
    "2015-03-03 18:12:12.297,10,19.158141,73.000201,0.0"
];

function file() {
    for(var i=0; i < test.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            time(i);
        }, 10000);
    }
}
function time(i) {
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var fileLoc = "D:\\test.csv";
    var file = fso.OpenTextFile(fileLoc, 2, true, 0);

    file.writeline(test[i]); 
    file.Close();
    alert('File created successfully at location: ' + fileLoc);
}
```

I need to update the data every 10 sec. I am approaching for the way to delete the existing latlong in CSV and put new latlong so the the object can be seen as a moving one.

Comment: Maintaining data record in plain text can be tricky. Is it possible to maintain data structure in program / database level, and replace the plain text if the I/O is limited?

Comment: I would keep an array of cells (array of array) in the memory of the JavaScript app and continuously print this array with a formatting function to the CSV file. It is much easier to overwrite the file with your current in-memory data, than editing CSV files. By the way, ActiveX won't work in browsers other than IE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a file for storage on the client side with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950131/how-can-i-create-a-file-for-storage-on-the-client-side-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

I believe storing a file on client side is not considered secure as per the standards and therefore not allowed [1]

However per your use case :

> CSV file to plot the data on the map....I need to **update the data every 10 sec**...to **delete the existing** latlong in CSV and **put new** latlong

You have this js var in your code

```
var test = [
"2015-03-03 18:12:12.297,1,19.1618,73.002,0.0",
"2015-03-03 18:12:12.297,2,19.158141,73.000202,0.0",
"2015-03-03 18:12:12.297,10,19.158141,73.000201,0.0"];
```

So instead you could try JS local storage [2], maybe something like this

```
//set in local storage
  localStorage.setItem('test','"2015-03-03 18:12:12.297,1,19.1618,73.002,0.0","2015-03-03 18:12:12.297,2,19.158141,73.000202,0.0","2015-03-03 18:12:12.297,10,19.158141,73.000201,0.0"');
//retrieve from local storage                        
    var test2= localStorage.getItem('test');

    console.log(test2);
```

[1] [How can I create a file for storage on the client side with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950131/how-can-i-create-a-file-for-storage-on-the-client-side-with-javascript)

[2] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage