# writing to a logfile with pure javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I’m developing a very simple web application, it just display’s static data and has no server, just html, css and javascript. One feature this application needs is to read and write to a log file every time the application is launched (index.html is opened in a browser). The log file is extremely simple, it should log 1 or 0 to a .txt file every time the app is launched. When the app is launched (open index.html) it should read the last value of the log file, save it as a variable for further logic and than write to the log file again. Is this possible with pure javascript/ jQuery? I’m trying to avoid using a node.js server or any databases as my client wants this as simple as possible. I’ve tried this jQuery below but I get this error… “jquery-2.2.3.js:9203 XMLHttpRequest cannot load’”. Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Get Log File
  function getLog() {
      $.ajax({
          url: 'file:///xxx/xxx/Desktop/app/logfile.txt', // fake path obvi
          dataType: 'text',
          success: function(text) {
              $("#Adaptors").text(text);
              setTimeout(getLog, 10000); // refresh every 10 seconds
              console.log("got Log: ", text);
          }
      })
  }

  getLog();
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API, as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950131/how-can-i-create-a-file-for-storage-on-the-client-side-with-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript, and probably many more.  Short answer: You can't make an HTTP request to the file system because the file system isn't a web server.

Comment: To follow up why this is difficult, it is because it is a HUGE security concern. If Javascript on any website you visit could immediately read/write files to anywhere on your filesystem, you would have viruses/all your information stolen from every shady website you visited.

Comment: I was nervous about this but it makes perfect sense, thanks for clarifying this for me and saving me time.

Answer (score 1):

**It is not really possible or convenient for client-side javascript to write anywhere on your filesystem**. What you should do **instead** is *create an endpoint on your server dedicating to logging*.

Your server-side javascript has the ability to read/write from the filesystem and therefor any logging must be done from there. I know firsthand this is easy with a `Node` / `ExpressJS` server.

For example your client could `POST` to a logging endpoint such as `/logs/error` with whatever logs/errors in a `JSON` object. The server would then format and write that log to the filesystem.

Edit: I should clarify that **it is possible** but not before the user tediously gives permission for every interaction with the filesystem the javascript wants to perform. Which not really what you want for logging.